# Text jumps when animation is played for a button focused state (button:focus)

Tags: css, html, animation

There is a keyframes animation for my button focused state. The problem is when the button comes in the focus state, the animation starts to play and that animation results in weird jumping of the button text.

How to prevent this weird shaky and jumpy behavior of text.

Thank you !

```css
.btn-inline {
    border: none;
    color: #eb2f64;
    font-size: inherit;
    border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .2s;
}


.btn-inline:hover {
    color: #333333;
}

.btn-inline:focus {
    outline: none;
    animation: Pulsate 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes Pulsate {
0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: none;
}
50%{
    transform: scale(1.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
100%{
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: none;
}

}
```

```html
<button class="btn-inline">Albufeira, Portugal</button>
```

Comment: just change animation: infinite to 1

Comment: @BearNithi it played my animation only once but i want to play it infinite time ?

Comment: What do u want to accomplish with the animation then?